# Obtaining the Probability of a Sentence using a Language Model

Tags: python, tensorflow, deep-learning, nlp, language-model

I have trained a language model using the following architecture,

```
model = tf.keras.Sequential([

tf.keras.layers.Embedding(total_words, 300, weights=[embeddings_matrix], input_length=inputs.shape[1], trainable=False),

tf.keras.layers.Bidirectional(tf.keras.layers.LSTM(150)),

tf.keras.layers.Dense(total_words, activation = 'softmax')

])
```

Note that I have used a pre-trained layer of word embeddings for this purpose.

What I would like to do now is, given an entirely new sentence, to generate the probability of that sequence based on this language model.

This is not about predicting the next word in the sequence, but about generating the probability of the entire sentence provided.

How do I do this in TensorFlow 2?
I have seen similar questions posted based on TensorFlow 1, but not with relation to the new version.